# homeomorphism between $[0,1]\times (0,1)$ and $[0,1)\times(0,1)$

Tags: general-topology

Can someone give a proof that why two spaces $[0,1]\times (0,1)$ and $[0,1)\times(0,1)$ are not homeomorphic?

Answer (score 1):

Both of those spaces are topological manifolds with boundary.

The boundary of $[0,1]\times(0,1)$ is disconnected - it has two pieces, $\{0\}\times(0,1)$ and $\{1\}\times (0,1)$.

In contrast, the boundary of $[0,1)\times(0,1)$ is connected - it is just $\{0\}\times(0,1)$.

(The boundary is the set of points that have a neighborhood isomorphic to euclidean half-space; [see the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_manifold#Manifolds_with_boundary) for more.)

Comment: This question is about topological spaces, not manifolds. The boundary of any topological space is empty (every point has the entire space as an open neighborhood).

Comment: @WimC: For any space $X$, we can examine the collection of points of $X$ that have a neighborhood homeomorphic to euclidean half-space. That's exactly what I explained that I was talking about.

Answer (score 1):

In the second space every compact set is contained in a larger compact set  with a connected complement (e.g. a closed rectangular region touching the left side). In the first space this does not hold (for example it fails for the compact set $[0,1]\times \{\tfrac{1}{2}\}$). Therefore these two sets cannot be homeomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

For any topological space $X$, let 
$$S_X= \{x\in X  \ | \ X-\{x\} \ \text{is contractible}\}$$
 The homeomorphism type of $S_X$ is clearly preserved under homeomorphisms of $X$. For $X=[0,1]\times (0,1)$, $S_X$ is disconnected. For $X=[0,1)\times(0,1)$, $S_X$ is connected.